# Making Search engine like google

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am building a search engine in ASP.NET which will show products not the links,my question is what is the trick or javascript function that when user type his search the search bar came on the top with results like google,i want that functionality in my search engine

Comment: not sure what you are after. Is it autocomplete functionality? can you elaborate?

Comment: i mean, its a pretty specific action.  I don't think there's a 'trick' or generic javascript function to do it.  You just gotta write the code.

Comment: do you have a screenshot that explains?

Comment: i mean asking to those ASP.NET developers will i have to redirect that to a page where a navbar is fixed on top or what should i do, i wanna make it like google that search bar should come on top on showing results to the user

Comment: @StianStandahl i just has the front end and data in my DB i want to implement the functionality like google whenever i search anything in seacrh bar the search bar should come along the results on the top

Comment: It sounds like the functionality you're looking for is called "autocomplete" or "type ahead".  There are many plugins to help with this, or you can write your own functionality.  What have you actually tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: i'm pretty sure he's referring to how, when you start typing at google.com, the search bar jumps from the middle of the screen to the top of the screen.  Not autocomplete.

Comment: @David i don't know what it's called but i wanna make it like google the search bar jumps on top

Comment: @MuhammadMateen: So, are you asking how to show/hide elements in JavaScript/jQuery?  How to modify elements?  Please clarify in the question.  This still goes back to *what have you tried?*  Applying different styles to HTML elements using jQuery is pretty straightforward, and there are many examples online.  It *could* be as simple as switching a CSS class on a containing element.

Comment: @David brother that's exactly my question from where should i start, should i kept a child page where a navbar is fixed already but that's not the approach i guess it should be responsive like google when google shows results the search bar is being shown on top of the results mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("header input").on("input", function(){
  if(this.value.length > 0){
    $("header").addClass("hasValue");
  }
});
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box; margin:0;}

header{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 24px;
}
header input{
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
/* ONCE INPUT HAS VALUE: */
header.hasValue{
  position:relative;
  top:0; left:0;
  transform: translate(0%, 0%); -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  text-align:left;
  background:#eee;
}
header.hasValue input{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <img src="//placehold.it/80x33/f0f/fff?text=LOGO" alt="LOGO">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search products">
</header>
```

Comment: @MuhammadMateen you're welcome. Please next time show some HTML, CSS of what you tried, would be easier to start from somewhere instead of doing all from scratch! Happy coding

Comment: J query is not working for me i guess or my CSS is wrong, i have also installed j query in my project and paste it in my header in asp.net project, but whenever i wrote something, nothing happens i don't know why
i think j query inside script tag is not working for me or please help

Comment: @MuhammadMateen place your `<script>` tag before the closing `</body>` to make sure all elements are ready and ready - or use document ready function wrapper- See jQuery documentation on that one.

Answer (score 0):

This bootsnip has a searchfield in a bootstrap navbar. 
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/navbar-search-add-on-bs-3

and if you were looking for a typeahead library
https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are building search engine on eCommerce portal, there is no any trick behind that. you can achieve similar functionality in may ways. I suggest to look at basics.

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/